# Adding string[] into an ArrayList using for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String[]> contact = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] record = new String[2];
int x1=1;

while(x1==3){

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        record[i]=input.nextLine();
    }
    contact.add(record);
    x1++;
}
```

I tried printing the list and found that the list holds the last record three times. The first two records (given during first two loops) are replaced by third record.

Comment: You always iterate from index 0. So you always replace all strings by last string.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should have initialized the string array inside while loop. So that you can avoid the old arrays in list being overridden. Like this.

```
    while (x1 <= 3) {
        String[] record = new String[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            record[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        contact.add(record);
        x1++;
    }
```

Comment: Why down vote? May I know the reason? This code has been accepted by the questioner.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are trying to add the array to the list multiple times. You should add a different array in each iteration of the while loop :

```
while(x1<=3){
    String[] record = new String[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        record[i]=input.nextLine();
    }
    contact.add(record);
    x1++;
}
```

I also assumed that `while(x1==3)` was a typo and you meant `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a flaw in your code. I've tried to address it below;

```
while(x1<=3){
    //create new string array
    String[] record = new String[2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        record[i]=input.nextLine();
    }
    contact.add(record);
    x1++;
}
```

Without redeclaring the array "record" you will have a reference to the original one added three times.

EDIT: saw that Eran has the same thing, but I missed the <= instead of == comparison as well. If you used ==, then you wouldn't have been able to enter the loop because the condition would have failed initially